# signalr error connect unauthorized, failed to start the transport

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm connecting to SignalR, but I'm getting an error:

> *WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:****/newhub?id=gic7TTgRm3kEY7NqJh6y0Q&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJITzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy13cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiS2liZXJpb25Db2RlckBtYWlsLnJ1IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYMMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9yb2xlIjoic3VwcGxpZXSiLCJuYmYiOjE1NTcxODA5MTAsImV4cCI6MTU1NzI2NDkxMCwiaXNzIjoiQXV0aFNlcnZlciIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTA1MjMvIn0.o1Q2435lkPmYTngLPMX40k0jGiykGE6Qn9UUDxjvt0o' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available*
>
> Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': null

Also 401 (Unauthorized) (But I'm sending a token)

Then:

> Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.

I can't understand. I'm getting an error, but everything works, and I get this error only after authorization adding.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SignalR tries to figure out which type of connection it should use and the `WebSocket` transport protocol is it's first try to establish a connection. If client and/or hub can not communicate with the selected protocol, it throws an error and tries the next one [have a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#transports-and-fallbacks). You can configure your clients connection to use specific protocols only - if needed.

Comment: Your JWT looks invalid. Have you checked with http://jwt.io?

Comment: Also, watch out for proxy on the way.  We thought we had websockets working, but it was failing over from ws:// to http longPolling in production because of the proxy.

Comment: Take a look at the authentication part of this: https://jamietech.com/2019/04/30/using-signalr-in-real-angular-app/ You need to tell your server to read the JWT token from the Query Params